# Can't send transaction using NODE-RED platform - "Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]"

Tags: web3js, transactions, accounts, nodejs

I'm trying to use NODE-RED (https://nodered.org/) on my RPi using web3 and geth to send simple transactions.

The code is the following:

```
//variables
var Web3 = global.get('web3');
var upc_abi = //contract abi
var upc_address = "0x15fC1a048C29C95605cbf906cC1f259573e49f4D";
var rpi_coinbase = "0x915c9fd51313cee6c94ae4f30d86edf2e79c8fe8";//accounts[0];
var rpi_1 = "0x0405468b70803989b7318d45d1a9c0bddffa6feb";

//web3.js, checking if node is running
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

if (!web3.isConnected()) {
    node.status({fill:"red",shape:"ring",text:"node not connected"});

} else {
    node.status({fill:"green",shape:"ring",text:"node connected"});
}

//fetching smart contract UPC
const Contract_upc = web3.eth.contract(upc_abi);
const Upc = Contract_upc.at(upc_address);

//function
node.send({payload:"Sending payment..."});

Upc.transferFrom(rpi_coinbase, rpi_1, 110, {
    from: rpi_coinbase,
    gas: 300000
});

return;
```

The function `transferFrom` that I use is taken from a token contract copied and pasted from the Ethereum website.

I tested the code using node.js and everything works fine, the tokens are correctly sent from one address to the other. However when I do it on NODE-RED the transaction is confirmed but the following error is returned:

> Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction].

My guess is that is somehow related to how I unlock the account. I use:

```
> personal.unlockAccount('0x915c9fd51313cee6c94ae4f30d86edf2e79c8fe8',"password", 99999)
```

Do you think the issue is related to this? If yes, how to solve it? If not, what then?